# Check if pointer is assigned

Tags: c

I am coding a spell checker which loads a dictionary into memeory and checks a given text for misspelled words. To implement this i would like to use a hash table. To handle collisions i'll use linked lists. Every word from the dictionary gets added to the beginning of the linked list of the corresponding hash.

I created an array of pointers to a struct called node. Here's my code for this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGHT + 1];
    struct node* next;
}
node;

node* table[HASHTABLE_SIZE];
```

My question is: Is it possible to check if table[x] is already pointing to a node in order to know if node.next should point to the rest of a linked list or should be NULL because its the first element in the linked list?

Comment: Do you mean "should point to ... or be `NULL`"? In that case, you are answering your own question. In the other case, your sentence is senseless.

Comment: I don't understand at all. You already know about `NULL`. You presumably understand `==`. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a hash table of size HASH_TABLE_SIZE which means there are HASH_TABLE_SIZE no. of liked list.Initially all linked list's head will be pointing to NULL. Inorder to know whether the table at index x is already having some element you just need to check whether the head at index x in the hash table in NULL or not.

```
if(table[x])
 //head is already created for the linked list having x as index
else
//head is NULL append the first node in this linked list at index x.And make this node new head
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (table[0] == NULL)
  // Create memory & allocate everything
```

Note that you can also do

```
if (table[0]->next == NULL)
   // assign next
```

Or even in C

```
if (!table[0]) // If table[0] does not exist
```